How can I use surveyor for abutment of dental implant properly?
I recently bought a machine called surveyor. Can you give me information about how to use this in the dental implant abutment and what rules will I apply in the abutment section?

Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For reasons mentioned in this post and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. See this list of helpful resources. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?
